# Getting data from a Telegram Bot API in a WebApp?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to display information from a `getChat` method in a WebApp, and then update chat title (via `setChatTitle` Bot API method). I take it I cannot send the `setChatTitle` request directly from a WebApp as that would require me to expose Bot Token in a client app. And calling `sendData` function provided to WebApp initData closes the WebApp. So is there a way to call Bot API methods from the Web App, directly or through requests to a bot?
If possible, I would prefer the solution with the bot hosted on Telegram servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to call Bot API directly from the web app. You should have your own server running as a layer between your web app and telegram bot API.